# Use AzMan RoleManager in conjunction with default ASP.NET Membership

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, membership-provider, azman

I would like to use the [AzMan RoleManager API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998314.aspx) in my existing webapplication. I'm already using the default ASP.NET membership provider which stores its users in the ASPNETDB database.

I quickly took a look at AzMan and administered my policy store using the supplied tool. However I was only able to add local pc users (Windows server 2003) to the store. **Is there an easy way to hook up AzMan with the default ASP.NET membership provider?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AzMan is based on the Windows Authorization Manager component, which has its own schema and management. It does not integrate with the ASP.NET membership provider to use it as a policy store, nor from which to select membership. AzMan can manage membership of any user for which it can determine a Security Identifier (SID), which can include users in a domain or an ADAM store. I don't believe there are any SIDs used in the ASP.NET Membership provider, unless you happen to be using Active Directory Membership Provider (but you already said you're using the SQL Server Membership Provider).

Short answer: No, there's not an easy way when starting from the SQL Server Membership Provider.